# Preview IFrame URL of a given Dropbox File Stat

Tags: dropbox-api

- The website provides IFrame preview
- The File API provides metadata

But I don't know how to get from the API the `_subject_uid` and `w` set in IFrame preview URL to embed the Preview in my own page.

The IFrame is calling :
https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get_htmlified/

There is also a sharing feature using a minifed URL with `makeUrl()` but I can't get IFrame URL

Comment: See also this question on the Dropbox developer forum: https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=112579.

Comment: Yes I ask the same question on DropBox Forum

Comment: Yes, and on Twitter. :-) Just trying to consolidate it all in one place.

Comment: Yes don't know if communities are the same, and it seems the question has been never asked. May be it's trivial ? But Dropbox provides somethig so cool I can't understood why no one want to use get_htmlified feature